# nginx и Cookies

Tags: nginx, сервер

В общем, такая проблема, есть сложное приложение, суть в чем - первым этапом происходит авторизация, потом запрос уходит на nginx, в котором сейчас работает примерно такое правило:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen  443;
            proxy_pass 192.168.10.1:443; 
    }   
}
```

По сути нужна балансировка, но ее нельзя сделать прямо тут, прописав несколько бэкендов в апстримах - нужно, чтобы выбирался конкретный сервер, на котором прошла авторизация (их несколько).

Идея решения была в чем - во время авторизации ставим куку с адресом сервера, а nginx ее читает, и на основании этого уже проксирует запрос к тому, или иному бэкенду. Попытка сделать это просто не увенчалась успехом (proxy_pass $cookie_myserver:443), так-же запрещено в этом месте делать подобный финт:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen  443;
        if ($cookie_myserver = "server1")
            proxy_pass 192.168.10.1:443; 
    }   
}
```

Так что вопрос таков - как сделать проксирование на определенный адрес, получив от клиента куки (или любой другой заголовок, могу добавлять все, что угодно)

Comment: `if` - зло. используйте [map](https://habr.com/ru/post/231277/). Там же написано в секции "Выбор upstream" как это запользовать.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, да, это намного удобней. Вот только есть небольшой нюанс - я проксирую udp, tcp трафик через секцию stream. Ее место не в основной http, а место map в http, в итоге proxy_pass не видит секцию map. Как быть в данном случае?

Comment: вообще странно, чтобы http поверх udp гонялся. у nginx есть несколько вариантов балансировки. в том числе с привязкой к IP адресу: ip_hash. может такой вариант устроит

Comment: В stream нет ничего кроме имени хоста (через ssl_preread), так что либо пробуйте как-использовать хост, либо поднимайте полноценный http сервер с терминированием ssl

Comment: @TotalPusher http2, quic, spdy и вот это вот всё работает по udp